# Insertion sort in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm making a list in C++ from scratch, not using the STL list funciton. My program is designed for the user to insert a new item (string) to the list, one at a time. The items are supposed to be sorted as they are inserted, and it partially works. The user is supposed to be able to print them forwards and backwards.

Examples:

- I insert: 1, 3, 2 - result forward: 1, 2, 3 - backwards: 3, 2, 1
- I insert 1, 3, 2, 4 - result forward: 1, 4, 2, 3 - backwards: 3, 2, 4, 1
- I insert 4, 2, 3 - result forward: 2, 3, 4 - backwards: 4, 3, 2
- I insert 4, 2, 3, 1 - result forward: 1, 4 - backwards: 1, 3 repetedly until program crashes

These are a few examples, I could include more. I can not for the life of me see what's wrong wth my code. I have gotten help from people I know who are great coders, but they were unable to see the problem, after looking at it for a couple hours. I've been stuck at this for days now, and I just don't see it.

Here is my code (comments are in Norwegian, sorry!):

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//definerer noden
struct node
{
    string data;    //det noden inneholder
    node* next;     //nestepeker
    node* prev;     //forrigepeker
};

//definerer funksjonene
bool isEmpty(node* first);
char menu();
void insertAsFirstElement(node* &first, node* &end, string data);
void insert(node* &first, node* &end, string data);
void remove(node* &first, node* &end, string data);
void showList(node* first);
void printBackwards(node* end);


//er noden tom?
bool isEmpty(node* first)
{
    if(first == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


//sender valgskjermen til konsollen
char menu()
{
    char choice;

    cout << "Welcome to LISTOMANIA 3000x! \n" << endl;
    cout << "Press <1> to add an item" << endl;
    cout << "Press <2> to remove item on top" << endl;
    cout << "Press <3> to display the list forward" << endl;
    cout << "Press <4> to display the list backwards" << endl;
    cout << "Press <5> to exit" << endl;
    cout << "\nInput: ";

    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}


//hvis lista er tom, sett inn node som første element:
void insertAsFirstElement(node* &first, node* &end, string data)
{
    cout << "temp is first\n";
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    first = temp;
    end = temp;
}


//hvis lista ikke er tom, sett inn noden sortert:
void insert(node* &first, node* &end, string data)
{
    if(isEmpty(first))
    {
        insertAsFirstElement(first, end, data);
    }
    else
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = data;
        node* n = first;

       while(n)
       {
            if(n->data > temp->data)
            {

                cout << "temp BEFORE n" << endl;
                temp->prev = n->prev;
                temp->next = n;
                n->prev = temp;

                if(temp->prev)
                {
                    temp->prev->next = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    first = temp;
                }
            }
            else if(n->data <= temp->data)
            {
                cout << "temp AFTER n" << endl;
                //temp = new node;
                //temp->data = data;
                temp->prev = n;
                temp->next = n->next;
                n->next = temp;

                if(temp->next)
                {
                    temp->next->prev = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    end = temp;
                }
                break;
            }

            n = n->next;
        }
    }
}


//sletter valgt node
void remove(node* &first, node* &end, string data)
{
    string delItem;
    node* temp;    

    if(isEmpty(first))
        cout << "\nNothing to delete, the list is empty!\n------------------------------------------------\n------------------------------------------------\n";
    else if(first == end)
    {
        cout << "\nYou removed <" << first->data << ">!" << endl;
        delete first;
        first = NULL;
        end = NULL;
        cout <<"------------------------------------------------\n------------------------------------------------\n";
    }
    else
    {
        node* temp = first;
        cout << "You removed <" << temp->data << ">!" << endl;
        first = first->next;
        delete temp;
        cout <<"------------------------------------------------\n------------------------------------------------\n";

    }
}


//skriver ut listen alfabetisk
void showList(node* first)
{
    node * temp = first;

    if(isEmpty(first))
    {
        cout << "\nThe list is empty!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nThe list contains: \n\n";
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    cout << "------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "------------------------------------------------\n";
}


//skriver ut listen omvendt alfabetisk
void printBackwards(node* end)
{
    node * temp = end;

    if(isEmpty(end))
    {
        cout << "\nThe list is empty!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nThe list contains: \n\n";
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
    }

    cout << "------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "------------------------------------------------\n";
}


//mainfunksjon
int main()
{
    node* first = NULL;
    node* end = NULL;
    char choice;
    string data;

    do
    {
        choice = menu();

        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':   cout <<"\nPlease add something to the list: ";
                        cin >> data;
                        insert(first, end, data);
                        cout << "------------------------------------------------\n------------------------------------------------\n";
                        break;
            case '2':   remove(first, end, data);
                        break;
            case '3':   showList(first);
                        break;
            case '4':   printBackwards(end);
                        break;
            case '5':   cout << "\nSystem exit...\n";
                        break;
            default: cout << "\nInvalid input!\n------------------------------------------------\n------------------------------------------------\n";
        }
    }while(choice != '5');

    return 0;
}
```

Just ignore the lines of hyphens, they are just there to make the program look prettier when it is run.

Please note that I am a beginner! There might be lots of other mistakes too, other than my problem. Also ignore the `remove` function, as I haven't gotten to that problem yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from more people, and we found a solution. Here is my `insert` fucntion:

```
//hvis lista ikke er tom, sett inn noden sortert:
void insert(node* &first, node* &end, string data)
{
    if(isEmpty(first))
    {
        insertAsFirstElement(first, end, data);
    }
    else
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = first;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        first->prev = temp;
        first = temp;
    }

    //sortering
    if(first != NULL)
    {
        node* current = first;
        node* prev = NULL;
        node* tempNode = NULL;


        while(current->next != NULL)
        {
           tempNode = current->next;

           //cout << "current: " << current->data << " tempNode: " << tempNode->data << endl;

           if(current->data > tempNode->data)
           {
               //cout << "swapped " << "current: " << current->data << " tempNode: " << tempNode->data << endl;
               swap(current->data, tempNode->data);
           }
           else
           {
               prev = current;
               current = current->next;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

This sorts the data if it is a `string`, with a little bug on numbers, interpreted as a `string`, which can be solved with converting all numbers to an `int`.

EDIT:
That bug with the nubmers isn't really a bug at all. The list thinks 11 is smaller than 5, but that is because every input is interprated as a `string`. So then if you think that 1 = a and  2 = b, then it makes perfect sense that 11 < 5. So if you want them to be sorted how it would logically be done, having 11 > 5, you'd have to convert all numbers to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

check two lines that I added with comments `//1.this line` and `//2.this line` the fist one is called when `temp<n` so you have to compare `temp` with previous node of `n`, and the second one is for when `temp>=n` so you have to do is to compare `temp` with next node of `n`. with what I said so far it is clear that you have to remove the line that I commented with `//4.you should remove this line : n = temp->next;` this is what cause your last problem. Also you have another mistake, you have to remove the `break;` it leaves your listed in the middle of the sort so your sort never completed and that is what cause the other problem.

```
while(n)
{
    if(n->data > temp->data)
    {
        cout << "temp BEFORE n" << endl;
        temp->prev = n->prev;
        temp->next = n;
        n->prev = temp;

        if(temp->prev)
        {
            temp->prev->next = temp;

        }
        else
        {
            first = temp;
        }
        n = temp->prev; //1.This line

    }
    else if(n->data <= temp->data)
    {
        cout << "temp AFTER n" << endl;
        //temp = new node;
        //temp->data = data;
        temp->prev = n;
        temp->next = n->next;
        n->next = temp;

        if(temp->next)
        {
            temp->next->prev = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            end = temp;
        }
        n = temp->next;       //2.This line
        //3.you should comment this line : break;
    }
    //4.you should remove this line : n = temp->next; 
}
```

Comment: Removing `break;` gives me `cout << "temp AFTER n" << endl;` repeatedly until the program crashes. Same with `cout << "temp BEFORE n" << endl;`, depending on what I put in and it what order. The sorting isn't quite fixed either, but somewhat improved, also depending on what i put in and in what order.